# Code in environment definition breaks when used from environment commands, but works when used directly

Tags: environments

I'm trying to build myself some nice semantic environments for writing my document so that I can keep formatting concerns separate from content and all that.  Unfortunately, I've run into an issue where defining an environment breaks where using the contents of the environment definition directly does not.

Specifically, the following breaks.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newenvironment{skills}
{
    \newenvironment{skill}[1]{##1 & \begin{itemize}}{\end{itemize} \\}
    \begin{tabular}{c p{0.8\textwidth}}
}
{
    \end{tabular}
    \let\skill\undefined
}

\begin{skills}
    \begin{skill}{Linux}
        \item Use Arch Linux as my daily driver to complete everyday computing tasks
    \end{skill}
\end{skills}

\end{document}
```

The error given is:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
<template> \unskip \hfil }
                          \hskip \tabcolsep \endtemplate 
l.16     \begin{skill}{Linux}
```

But the following works.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newenvironment{skills}
{                                                                                
    \begin{tabular}{c p{0.8\textwidth}}
}
{
    \end{tabular}
}

\begin{skills}
    Linux & \begin{itemize}
        \item Use Arch Linux as my daily driver to complete everyday computing tasks
    \end{itemize} \\
\end{skills}

\end{document}
```

I'm using xelatex.

```
$ xelatex --version
XeTeX 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994 (TeX Live 2022/Arch Linux)
kpathsea version 6.3.4
Copyright 2022 SIL International, Jonathan Kew and Khaled Hosny.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the XeTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the XeTeX source.
Primary author of XeTeX: Jonathan Kew.
Compiled with ICU version 71.1; using 71.1
Compiled with zlib version 1.2.12; using 1.2.12
Compiled with FreeType2 version 2.12.0; using 2.12.1
Compiled with Graphite2 version 1.3.14; using 1.3.14
Compiled with HarfBuzz version 4.2.0; using 4.3.0
Compiled with libpng version 1.6.37; using 1.6.37
Compiled with pplib version v2.05 less toxic i hope
Compiled with fontconfig version 2.14.0; using 2.14.0
```

What gives?

Comment: Welcome. Why defining `skill` every time `skills` is used?

Comment: Anyway, you cannot begin an environment in an alignment cell and end it in another.

Comment: I am defining `skill` the way that I am so that it isn't available outside of the `skills` environment.

What do you mean by alignment cell?  I'm not splitting the `itemize` environment between table cells, even inside of the environment definition (unless the environment definition means something other than what I think it means).